# PS2 Eye Toy and Cheese webcam app

Tags: 18.04, webcam, cheese, v4l

I have a Sony PS2 Eye Toy USB Camera.

```
$ lsusb  | grep Sony
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 054c:0155 Sony Corp.
```

When I plug it into a Ubuntu 18.04 machine, and start Cheese, then no devices are found.

vlc will not see the device either.

Video 4 Linux does see the device:

```
$ v4l2-dbg --info
Driver info:
    Driver name   : ov519
    Card type     : EyeToy USB camera Namtai
    Bus info      : usb-0000:00:14.0-2
    Driver version: 4.15.18
    Capabilities  : 0x85200001
        Video Capture
        Read/Write
        Streaming
        Extended Pix Format
        Device Capabilities
```

But fswebcam, however, **is able** to grab an image (albeit with frequent vsync artifacts.)

Why do some apps see the camera, and others do not?

Comment: My eyetoy cam is working in the browser (firefox) when using jitsi.
But in cheese or microsoft teams it's very dark (not being recognized).